Чи відмінюється жіноче іншомовне прізвище Алізада́ (наголос на останній а)
Чи відмінюється жіноче іншомовне прізвище Алізада́ (наголос на останній а)?
У підручнику Авраменка за 2018 рік (10 клас) указано, що іншомовні прізвища на наголошений -а не відмінюємо:

Не відмінюються іншомовні прізвища:

на -а з попереднім голосним і на наголошений -а: Моруа, Жоффруа, Дюма.


А також у правописі, але це проєкт за 2018 рік (стор. 135):

Особливості відмінювання власних назв іншомовного походження
Крім власних назв не відмінюємо також:

прізвища й чоловічі особові імена на -а (-я) в наголошеній позиції:
Дюма́, Дерріда́, Золя́, Зія́, Ніколя́, Шота́


Тому я сумніваюся…

Не бачу підстав для невідмінювання, принаймні серед тих, що перераховано в «Правописі» 2019 року в § 140 «Відмінювання слів іншомовного походження» є розділ «Невідмінювані іменники іншомовного походження» (с. 165–166):

Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюємо, а саме:
1) іменники на -а з попереднім голосним: амплуá, боá, буржуá; Бенуá, Валуá, Джóшуа, Жоффруá, Нікарáгуа, Пáпуа;
2) односкладові слова на -а, -я: бра, па, спа, фа, ля;
3) іменники на -е, -є: валідé, ду́че, желé, кабарé, кабернé, кафé, кашнé, негліжé, пенснé, пікé, суфлé, турнé, шалé, шосé; ательє́, сомельє́; Беранжé, Гéйне, Гéте, Дáнте, Туапсé; Барб’є́, Готьє́, Ле Корбюзьє́, Лавуазьє́, Рамбує́;
4) іменники на -и, -і, -ї: вíскі, ефéнді, колíбрі, мерсí, парí, пóні, таксí; Алматú, Амангельдú, Тбілíсі; Анрí, Гальвáні, Россíні, Фірдоусí, Шéллі; Віньї́, Шантії́;
5) іменники на -о: бюрó, депó, жабó, є́вро, казинó, какáо, каудúльйо, кімонó, кінó, крéдо, лотó, маéстро, метрó, рáдіо, рéтро; Макáо; Антóніо, Арнó, Базíліо, Буалó, Ванó, Віардó, Ву́дро, Дідрó, Джо, Мáріо, Лáо, Лонгфéлло, Пікáссó, По, Торквáто, Тáссо; Вóльво, Пежó, Ренó; за традицією відмінюємо
винó, пальтó, ситрó;
6) іменники на -у, -ю: какаду́, рагу́, рандеву́, фрáу, шóу, Баку́, Катманду́, Палáу, Снóу; інженю́, інтерв’ю́, меню́, парвеню́, Кюсю́, Сю_;
7) топоніми з компонентами -лейн, -ривер, -роуд, -сквер, -стріт: на Дру́рі-лейн, біля Пáрк-лейн, біля Фолл-Рúвер, на Éббі-рóуд, на Монтріóл-рóуд, на Тáймс-сквер, на Áдам-стрíт, біля Рúджент-стрíт, на Сент-Джéймс-стрíт;
8) етикетні означення жінки, що закінчуються на приголосний: мадáм, мадемуазéль, міс, мíсис, фрéкен, фрóйляйн, хану́м;
9) жіночі особові імена, що закінчуються на -й і на твердий приголосний (крім губних): Беатрíс, Гюльчатáй, Долóрес, Елмáс, Енн, Жаннéт, Ірéн, Кáрмéн, Кім, Клодíн, Ленóр, Мáргарет, Мерсéдес, Монíк, Тріш, Фарáх та ін.
Примітка. Жіночі імена, що закінчуються на губний або м’який приголосний, відмінюємо: Ізабéль — Ізабéлі, Етéль — Етéлі, Жізéль — Жізéлі, Зейнáб — Зейнáбі, Мішéль — Мішéлі, Нікóль — Нікóлі, Сесíль — Сесíлі, Руф — Ру́фі.

Також у § 142 «Відмінювання прізвищ» у пункті 1 є примітка 3 (с. 168), яка каже, що ті неслов'янські прізвища, які все-таки відмінюються, роблять це аналогічно до слов'янських прізвищ — і це стосується зокрема прізвищ 1-ї відміни (на -а, -я), причому як жіночих, так і чоловічих:

Мáйборода — Мáйбороди, Мáйбороді, Мáйбороду…
Мамалúга — Мамалúги, Мамалúзі…
Панібудьлáска — Панібудьлáски, Панібудьлáсці…
<…>
Примітка 3. За відповідними відмінами відмінюємо неслов’янські
змінювані прізвища:
<…>
Окуджáва — Окуджáви, Окуджáві…


За аналогією зі словом "Шехерезада" (іменник жіночого роду, відмінюється; джерело: "Словники України online") — напевно, теж відмінюється.

Підтримую. Теоретично наголос на останній склад (Алізада́ проти Шехереза́да) міг би вплинути, але слова 1-ї відміни з наголосом на останній склад також відмінюються (наприклад, сковорода́).
